# Header div follow other fixed div on scroll horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I have try to make a jQuery script that makes a div follow another fixed div. But I'm not succeeding.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="masterholder">
 <div class="item">
  <div class="headeritem"></div>
  <div class="bodyitem"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="item">
  <div class="headeritem"></div>
  <div class="bodyitem"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="item">
  <div class="headeritem"></div>
  <div class="bodyitem"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

When I scroll from the top 200px `($(window).scrollTop() > 200)` then all `".headeritem"` are "static", but when I scroll horizontal, I need the `".headeritem"` to follow the `".bodyitem"`, means that the `".headeritem"` is always over the `".bodyitem"` even when I scroll horizontally.

Comment: Do you have a working example that we can see?

Comment: NO I dont... I have try many approach, nothing works

Comment: show us what have do done

Comment: you want the "item" elements to be horizontally or vertically ordered? At least, post a picture or something..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your looking for:

HTML:

```
 <div class="masterholder">
 <div class="item">
  <div class="headeritem"></div>
  <div class="bodyitem"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="item">
  <div class="headeritem"></div>
  <div class="bodyitem"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  width: 6000px;
  height: 1550px;;
}

.masterholder {
  width: 3000px;
  height: 700px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.headeritem {
  position:fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.bodyitem {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
}
```

JS:

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollLeft() > 200) {
    $('.bodyitem').addClass('sticky');
  } else {
    $('.bodyitem').removeClass('sticky');
  }
});
```

fiddle for demonstration:
https://jsfiddle.net/Nicholas9114/w7pgckga/6/